# Get the movementSpeed based on the player HP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the players speed to be affected by the speed, for example if 20 hp is the max , at 20 hp the player would be at 10 speed, but then if it gets to 5, it would interpolate to go between max and min.

I´ve heard about mathf.Lerp but I am not getting the expected results. Any advice?

```
   private void CalculateMovementAttackSpeed()
    {
        movementSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(10, 5, this.hp);
        Debug.Log(movementSpeed);
    }
```

10 is the maximum movement speed the player can reach, and 5 de minimum.

Comment: The third value of `Mathf.Lerp` should be a decimal betweeen 0 and 1. Try doing `this.hp/20`, or what ever your max hp is. The documentation Ive seen for it does really provide any information, but I did find a unity answer post that might [help](https://answers.unity.com/questions/237294/how-the-heck-does-mathflerp-work.html).

Comment: @ChilliPenguin That worked! Thanks for your answer <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may want remapping rather than interpolating between two numbers.

```
public static float Remap (this float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2) 
{
    return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
}
```

And then you can get the desired speed from the health (where 20 is max HP and 10 is max speed):

```
private void CalculateMovementAttackSpeed()
{
    movementSpeed = Remap(this.hp, 0f, 20f, 5f, 10f);
    Debug.Log(movementSpeed);
}
```

Comment: That worked in a more precise way than the other answer! For this case it went great, but if we had more values, wouldn´t the method parameters be too large?